# How to check if list element is present in array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list

```
bulk_order
Out[230]: 
[3    523
Name: order_id, dtype: object]
```

And I have an array. Its a series but I am accessing it with `values`

```
clusters_order_ids.values
Out[231]: 
array([['520', '521', '524', '527', '532'], ['528'], ['531'],
   ['525', '526', '533'], ['519', '523', '529', '534', '535'], ['530']],     
dtype=object)
```

Now I want to check whether `list element 523` is present in above array and if it is there I want to delete it.

I am doing following in python

```
bulk_order in clusters_order_ids.values
```

But It gives me `False` output

Comment: `clusters_order_ids.values` is a list of lists, not numbers.

Comment: Use any() to just check if the element exists. `any(bulk_order in id_list for id_list in clusters_order_ids)`

Comment: Is your array a numpy array or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list is not a list, but a list of lists.

If you want to delete the whole list containing something in list ['523']:

```
orders = [['520', '521', '524', '527', '532'], ['528'], ['531'], ['525', '526', '533'], ['519', '523', '529', '534', '535'], ['530']]
remove_order_with_ids = ['523'] # or bulk_order 
orders = [order for order in orders if not set(remove_order_with_ids).intersection(set(order))]
print orders
# [['520', '521', '524', '527', '532'], ['528'], ['531'], ['525', '526', '533'], ['530']]
```

If you only want to delete items in ['523'] from the inner list(s):

```
orders = [['520', '521', '524', '527', '532'], ['528'], ['531'], ['525', '526', '533'], ['519', '523', '529', '534', '535'], ['530']]
remove_order_with_id = ['523'] # or bulk_order 
new_orders = []
for order in orders:
    new_orders.append([item for item in order if item not in remove_order_with_id])
print new_orders
# [['520', '521', '524', '527', '532'], ['528'], ['531'], ['525', '526', '533'], ['519', '529', '534', '535'], ['530']]
```

Comment: It doesn't delete either. neither entire list containing  `523` nor `523`

Comment: Works for `remove_order_with_id = '523'` but not for `remove_order_with_id = bulk_order`

Comment: Could it be that you need to access the order_id from the bulk order: remove_order_with_id = bulk_order.order_id?

Comment: bulk_order is a list.

Comment: Is bulk_order a list of order_ids, also containing the number 3? In that case, what should happen if the array contains 3?

Comment: 3 is an index,not a list element

Comment: thanks alot. was hunting for it for so long. I used your solution and @tglaria solution combined.. `out1=[item for sublist in bulk_order for item in sublist]` and then I assigned this to `remove_order_with_id=out1`

Answer (score 3):

Try this (from [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)):

```
l = clusters_order_ids.values
out = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
print (bulk_order in out)
```

For the deletion, you'd have to enter on each list so:

```
for sublist in clusters_order_ids.values:
    if bulk_order in sublist:
        sublist.remove(bulk_order)
        if not sublist:
            #do something to remove the empty list
        break;
```

Comment: Use any() to just check if the element exists.
`any(bulk_order in id_list for id_list in clusters_order_ids)`

Comment: @tglaria It gives me output as `False`

Comment: @user2927983 What gives you output as `False`?